# Regex for linkifying urls

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to linkify URLs inside a text content. I know there are so many questions and answers for this purpose but I have a little bit different situation here.

What I want to do is converting this:

```
the best search engine is [out: http://google.com google].
```

into this:

```
the best search engine is <a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">google</a>.
```

or converting this:

```
the best search engine is [in: google].
```

into this:

```
the best search engine is <a href="http://mywebsite.com/google">google</a>.
```

What is the easiest way to do this in PHP for a newbie?

The best point I've reached is this:

```
$message = preg_replace("'(in: (.*))'Ui","(in: <a href=\"link.php?t=\\1\"><b>\\1</b></a>)",$message);
```

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: Why the difference between `out:` and `in:`? Why is that prefix necessary?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use `http://mywebsite.com/google`, just `/google` will behave identically since it will look for an absolute path in the current website

Comment: @tadman just for better understanding and also to avoid converting every text inside brackets into links.

Comment: @Washington Guedes good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the first one, you can use this regex: [`\[out:\s*([^\s]*)\s*(.*)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/egrYXf/1) and replace with `<a href="\1" rel="nofollow">\2</a>`.
- For the second case, use [`\[in:\s*(.*)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/egrYXf/2), and replace with `<a href="http://mywebsite.com/\1">\1</a>`.

Here's some code to do it, using `$result = preg_replace(pattern, substitution, input)`:

```
$result1 = preg_replace("/[out:\s*([^\s]*)\s*(.*)]/", '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow">\2</a>', $input);    
$result2 = preg_replace("/[in:\s*(.*)]/", '<a href="mywebsite.com\\1">\\1</a>', $input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am able to run it after a few changes. Let me accept your answer after you have edit the code as follows for others:

Comment: For the first one: $result = preg_replace("/\[out:\s*([^\s]*)\s*(.*)\]/", '<a href="\1" rel="nofollow">\2</a>', $input);

Comment: For the second one: $result = preg_replace("/\[in:\s*(.*)\]/", '<a href="http://mywebsite.com/\\1">\\1</a>', $input);

Comment: Was it the quotes in the pattern that were missing? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use those two regular expressions:

```
\[in:\s*([^\[\]]*?)\]
\[out:\s*([^\[\]]*?)\s([^\[\]]*?)\]
```

Here is an example for the matching the groups in JavaScript (live test):

```js
var regex1 = /\[in:\s*([^\[\]]*?)\]/g;
var regex2 = /\[out:\s*([^\[\]]*?)\s([^\[\]]*?)\]/g
var text = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
text = text.replace(regex1, '<a href="http://mywebsite.com/$1">$1</a>');
text = text.replace(regex2, '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow">$2</a>');

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="main">
  the best search engine is [out: http://google.com google].
  the best search engine is [in: google].
</div>
```

---

And here the same in PHP:

```
<?php
$regex1 = "/\\[in:\\s*([^\\[\\]]*?)\\]/";
$regex2 = "/\\[out:\\s*([^\\[\\]]*?)\\s([^\\[\\]]*?)\\]/";
$text = 'the best search engine is [out: http://google.com google]. the best search engine is [in: google].';

$text = preg_replace($regex1, '<a href="http://mywebsite.com/$1">$1</a>', $text);
$text = preg_replace($regex2, '<a href="$1" rel="nofollow">$2</a>', $text);

echo $text;
?>
```

[*Live example in PHP Sandbox online*](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ebed0dfc48ea42ace1cd80e6889583e9cc0d0f9)